How much of a power projection capability has China's navy demonstrated in the Indian Ocean?
Some analysts have been fretting/talking about a "triangle of death" encircling India, meaning Chinese access to ports in Pakistan, Sri Lanka, and Bangladesh.
How much of a power projection capability has the Chinese navy demonstrated in that region though (roughly Indian Ocean + Arabian Sea + Bay of Bengal)? Do they e.g. regularly sortie aircraft carriers or submarines in that region?

The term "demonstrated" and "capability" are rather strongly in tension here. China has not "demonstrated" much by actually deploying naval forces beyond participating with a small number of smaller naval ships in some fairly minor joint anti-piracy campaigns in the Red Sea/Somalia coast area. China's capabilities based upon the know ships in its fleet and their capabilities is vastly greater but it hasn't actually flexed that muscle. Which are you asking about?

@ohwilleke: reminds me of the fleet-in-being logic during some past WW.

Almost all the relevant data is at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Liberation_Army_Navy or at links therein.

@ohwilleke: not much mention of the Indian Ocean there.

It lists the ship capabilities of the Chinese navy and essentially all major operations it has undertaken (with links to ship by ship capabilities). It says little about the Indian Ocean because the Chinese Navy has done very little in the Indian Ocean except to cross it for the 2008 anti-piracy operation.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever, How much of a power projection capability... --- how can it be quantified?

@user366312 Simple measures is to talk about size, type, and number of ships and the frequency of the activity in the region.

Actually moving surface units into the Indian Ocean in hostile conditions, if one looks at a map, would have them run a gauntlet of nations that are not all friendly.  China might do it, but it's unlikely to be done without a very good reason.  So, yes, article looks a bit hyperbolish and the Q seems warranted enough.

It's a badly posed question but the last sentence is valid. Just delete the rest!

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_projection and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navy but OK, let's stick with just military. FFS.

To somewhat/partly self-answer on the fleet in being angle...

According to a 2020 China Maritime Studies Institute report, China has more than 100 warships and submarines that can operate in the Indian Ocean. This figure is likely to rise as the Chinese navy expands its surface combatant fleet to 435 ships by 2030.

As for actual/past operations, if we take ohwilleke's suggestion to refer to Wikipedia's article on PLA's navy, that barely mentions the Indian Ocean, except for some anti-piracy sorties. (Whether that wiki article is a complete enough account is another matter.)
Another article has bit more of a historical perspective/trend

In 1999 there was not a single PLAN port visit in the Indian Ocean region, however, since 2010 the PLAN has averaged close to 20 port visits a year. Furthermore, China is the only country to set up embassies in all six island nations in the Indian Ocean.
[...] The PLAN has eight 903/A supply ships, which have been used in the Gulf of Aden [...]
According to the Indian Navy, at any given time there are between six and eight PLAN warships in the northern Indian Ocean. Most of these vessels are providing public goods in the form of anti-piracy patrols.

And the piece is somewhat dismissive of the present-day importance of these, due to lack of aircraft carriers in the composition:

However, in the absence of effective air cover, any PLAN flotilla in the region will not be able to engage in any meaningful combat with a state that has either its own naval aviation, or nearby land-based fighter jets. Furthermore, these deployments are still small compared to the American and Indian naval forces in the region. The absence of air cover cannot be underestimated, and this is a severe impediment to the PLAN’s ability to effectively project power beyond the symbolic showing of the flag. While the PLAN will eventually master the art of carrier-based aviation, until this is realized, it will not be able to engage in combat operations beyond dealing with pirates or other relatively low-risk missions such as evacuations.

The same piece ventures a guess regarding the two-oceans (Pacific and Indian) approach:

Beijing is unlikely to formally declare an Indian Ocean fleet before one is operational, and even then, for political reasons, it may not call it a fleet.

As for submarines, an Indian source points out that China has [somewhat] regularly included (I guess one) nuclear-powered submarines in this force:

In 2013, China announced the deployment of a Shang-class nuclear attack submarine in the Indian Ocean, ostensibly as part of its naval flotilla for anti-piracy patrols in the Gulf of Aden. [...] Following this deployment, Chinese submarines and support vessels have been making regular forays into the Indian Ocean, often alongside PLAN’s Anti-Piracy Escort Force (APEF) flotilla.

In 'Sea Guardian 3', conducted in 2023 together with Pakistan, China included a conventionally powered submarine, along with 3 of their surface combatants, and a support ship. The (2024) article claims this was the 8th time a Chinese submarine was in the Indian ocean since 2013.
China has been building a fair number of subs. They have about 60 now (only 12 of which are nuclear powered though), but they reportedly will increase the total to 80 by 2035. Related, reportedly they've been getting serious about mapping the depths of the Indian Ocean, for subsurface warfare.

This mostly matches ohwilleke's comment. China has actively deployed very little in the Indian Ocean. They could deploy a lot more but how much power that would actually project is hard to judge because they haven't done it, it is all theoretical.

@quarague: yeah, but it seem that annoying India that way is not on their list of  priorities for now. India however has already "annoyed them back" by e.g. selling their best anti-ship missiles ot the Philippines etc. https://jamestown.org/program/beijings-aggression-behind-emerging-india-philippines-defense-relationship/

FWIW, while I cite to Wikipedia in my comment, I review about sixty articles in defense/military affairs specialty publications every week, with maybe one in five or six of them discussing China in some manner. So, I have some comfort that the Wikipedia article isn't missing anything really significant.

Pakistan with 8 frigates, 8 military submarines, and a variety of smaller naval vessels, as well as a decent sized air force, also has more military power in the Indian Ocean than the PLAN. India and Pakistan are also among only a handful of countries in the world which have engaged in actual naval battles post-WWII. The Indo-Pakistani Naval War of 1971 was the first major naval war post World War II. Sri Lanka has a single frigate and some smaller ships as its sole navy and only 5-6 fighter aircraft in its air force. Bangladesh has 7 frigates, 2 subs, many warplanes, and many smaller ships.

@ohwilleke: yeah, fair point that one could consider Pakistan's China's ally in some circumstances, particularly a conflict with India. Coordination between them didn't exactly work out in the past though. Pakistan mostly warred with India without China's help and vice-versa.

It is also worth recalling that India, Pakistan, and China all have nuclear missiles. https://instituteforglobalaffairs.org/2023/05/bytes-nuclear-weapons-you/

(August 19, 2022) - Chinese navy vessel arrives at Sri Lanka port to security concerns from India

“The Yuan Wang 5 is a powerful tracking vessel whose significant aerial reach – reportedly around 750km – means that several ports in Kerala, Tamil Nadu and Andhra Pradesh could be on China’s radar,”

(August 16, 2023) - Chinese 'spy ship' Yuan Wang 5 docks in Sri Lanka despite Indian concern

Foreign security analysts quoted by Reuters describe the Yuan Wang 5 as one of China's latest generation space-tracking ships, used to monitor satellite, rocket and intercontinental ballistic missile launches.

(Nov 13, 2023) - China Holds Naval Drills With Pakistan in Arabian Sea

The ministry said several warships and submarines, including the guided-missile destroyer Zibo, guided-missile frigates Jingzhou and Linyi, and a People’s Liberation Army (PLA) Marine Corps unit, are participating in the Sea Guardian-3 exercise.

(May 8, 2024) - Chinese warships have been docked in Cambodia for 5 months

Chinese warships have been docked in Cambodia for 5 months

China sends warships for massive drill with Cambodia

The two warships — Jingangshan amphibious warfare ship and Qijiguang training ship — arrived at Cambodia's Sihanoukville port. The commercial port is north of the Ream naval base, where two other Chinese corvettes have been docked for the last five months.

To be continued...

Not enough to actually matter to India yet - if PLAN was a serious threat to India's maritime security, India would officially be in the QUAD security alliance to neutralise it. China knows this and that is why it is hesitant / slow on its plan for an Indian Ocean fleet. India has also been focusing on upgrading its Navy (like building the submarine version of Brahmos, building new aircraft carriers and submarines). It has also been supplying Brahmos missiles to others in South Asia that feel threatened by PLAN's aggressive overtures in the area.
But now that Ms. Sheik Hasina has been deposed in Bangladesh though, things are more tense for India as both China and the US have been vying for a naval base there, which would make India more vulnerable. If the Chinese Navy manages to has its way in Bangladesh, it can theoretically partly reduce the threat from QUAD for PLAN.

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57278/does-the-usa-plan-to-establish-a-military-facility-on-saint-martins-island-in-t/57280#57280

Not my DV, but I'm not sure what you mean by "if PLAN was a serious threat  [...] India would officially be in the QUAD alliance". AFAICT the "Quad" includes India by definition. I guess you mean they'd make the alliance more formal, or something like that.

Also, the level of threat from China is probably not the only consideration. If India were to enter a formal defense treaty with Japan and the US, that would surely irk Russia, which is still a supplier of importance to India, both in terms of weapons and oil. So, they did some partial pushback against China like selling Brahmos missiles to the Philippines and signed that coop agreement that allowed US planes to land in the Andaman islands.

@MakeStackExchangeGREAT4ever India sees QUAD as more than a military alliance, and the QSD is an attempt to convince India to join the military alliance, which it is loathe to for many, many, reasons.

With Russia we have a comfortable relationship that spans decades now, based on mutual trust. This includes at the military leadership level too. So Russia is very attuned to how indians think about foreign policy and security, especially vis Pakistan and China (against whom they've given us military intelligence and advise in the past too). It knows that India will not join any military alliance unless it is desperate. It takes steps to ensure we do not become "desperate".
